# ¿Como puedo trabajar con eventos en un proyecto en meteor, por ejemplo animate()?

Tags: jquery, css, nodejs, meteor

Estoy trabajando con componentes React y Meteor pero como puedo inscrutar alguna especie de animacion con jquery animate(), he leido algo sobre 'ComponentDidMount(), por decir mis componentes son de esta manera, como puedo referenciar los nodos del DOM para poder ejecutar las animacionones?

este un ejemplo de una navbar pero no como puedo referencias las className para trabajar con jquery?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
//import './Landing';
// https://secapaz.com/handwritting/     s è  c a p a z 
 //  <Link to="/registro">crea una cuenta.</Link>

export default class NavbarLanding extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <div className="navbar-landing">
            <nav>
                <div>
                        <ul className="ul-landing">
                                {/* <img src="./public/images/flat-rocket.jpg"></img> */}
                                <li className="navbar-title"><a>Landing </a></li>
                            <div className="navbar-menu">
                                <li><a>acerca</a></li>
                                <li><a>portafolio</a></li>
                                <li><a>contacto</a></li>
                                <button className="btn"onClick={() => Accounts.logout()}>Logout</button>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                </div>
             </nav>
        </div>
        );
    };
}
//export default NavbarLanding;
NavbarLanding.reactProptype = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) es un framework que usa una tecnología conocida como [Virtual DOM](https://medium.com/@lehiarteaga/entendiendo-el-virtual-dom-bb8b62ce25c1); esta tecnología no interactúa a cada momento con el DOM original, en su lugar, realiza una serie de cálculos para saber qué partes actualizar y no sobrecargar así el documento con repaints innecearios.

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) trabaja sobre el DOM real; por lo que usar jQuery con React para cuestiones de animaciones, entre otras es una mala idea. Por otro lado, puedes realizar tu propia animación simplemente con [css](/questions/tagged/css) o usando una librería como [animate](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) **utilizando el estado del componente** para correr y/o parar la animación.

**Ejemplo**

```js
class Animation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animationRunning: true,
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ animationRunning: false });
    }, 3000);
  }
 
  render() {
    const loaderCss = this.state.animationRunning ? ['loader-wrapper', 'visible'] : ['loader-wrapper'];
    const contentCss = this.state.animationRunning ? ['content'] : ['content', 'visible'];
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className={loaderCss.join(' ')}>
          <div className="loader"/>
        </div>
        <div className={contentCss.join(' ')}>
          <h1>Página principal</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const node = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Animation />, node);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.loader-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FDC800;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.loader-wrapper.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}
.content.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

h1 {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 25px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Loader */
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: spin 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.loader:before {
  left: -3.5em;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 3.5em;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Te agradezco por la informaciòn pero como puedo hcer referencia de por ejemplo de la clase animated en un boton, en la plantilla agreguè la referencia "animate bounceInLeft" pero no funciona la animacion tengo que importar algunaa libreria o agregar alguna otra directiva                                               <button className="btn animated bounceInLeft"onClick={() => Accounts.logout()}>Logout</button>

Comment: @GerardoBautista disculpa la demora. Si quieres hacer un logout animado, es muy similar. Debes de poner las clases de la animación fijas menos `animated`, esto porque la clase `animated` la agregarás **de acuerdo al estado**. Me explico, en el estado pones una bandera que indique cuando mostrar la animación, entonces, cuando presionas `logout` actualizas la bandera y de esta manera React se encarga de agregar la clase `animated` para dar inicio a la animación. Puedes complementarlo con un `setTimeout` para que después de unos segundos redireccione al login por ejemplo.

Comment: Encontré una pagina con diferentes tipos de animaciones para React, a alguien le puede servir lamentablemente la pagina viene en inglés pero esta muy bien explicado. https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-animations-in-depth-433e2b3f0e8e